# Equivalences of bounded sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

$\newcommand{\diam}{\operatorname{Diam}}$
$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$

**Definition:** Let $X$ be a metric space, $M \subseteq X$ is bounded if $\diam(M) < \infty$

Let $(X,d)$, $X \not=  \emptyset$, be a metric space and $M \subseteq X$. Show that the following are equivalent:

(i) $M$ is bounded.

(ii) $\exists_{x \in X}\left\{\exists_{r > 0}\left[ M \subseteq B_{r}(x)\right]
\right\}$

(iii) $\forall_{x \in X}\left\{\exists_{r > 0}\left[ M \subseteq B_{r}(x)\right]\right\}$

**Attempt (following suggestions from you):**

Suppose $M$ is bounded. We want to see that $\exists_{x \in X}\left\{\exists_{r > 0}\left[ M \subseteq B_{r}(x)\right]\right\}$.

(iii) $\rightarrow$ (ii)

Suppose that $\forall_{x \in X}\left\{\exists_{r > 0}\left[ M \subseteq B_{r}(x)\right]\right\}$. We want to see that $\exists_{x \in X}\left\{\exists_{r > 0}\left[ M \subseteq B_{r}(x)\right]\right\}$.

By hypothesis it is true for any $x \in X$. Therefore, in particular, it is true for some $x \in X$. Hence, $\exists_{x \in X}\left\{\exists_{r > 0}\left[ M \subseteq B_{r}(x)\right]\right\}$.

(ii) $\rightarrow$ (i)

Suppose that $\exists_{x \in X}\left\{\exists_{r > 0}\left[ M \subseteq B_{r}(x)\right]\right\}$. We want to see that $M$ is bounded. Suppose by contradiction that $M$ is not bounded.

By hypothesis above, we have that $\diam(M) = \infty$. So there exists $m_{1},m_{2} \in M$ such that they are arbitrary far. It is a contradiction! Because the ball $B_{r}(x)$, which has a finite radius $r$, can not contain its points $m_{1}$ and $m_{2}$ but they are inside $M$.

How can I deduce (i) $\rightarrow$ (iii)?

Comment: You should give the definition of "$M$ is bounded" you need to use because (ii) is sometimes used as the definition, making (i) and (ii) identical. In a revision made while I was writing the previous sentence, you've included the definition in the proof, so I guess OK now.

Comment: I've tried to fix a few things, mainly the issue where you have $d$ representing two different notions, but I'm not sure I've caught all of it. You should go back over things in a mathematical-grammar way to make sure no typos in notation and such.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks! I am new in wrtting in english

Answer (score 1):

Your treatment of the case $M=\varnothing$ is unclear: at one point you say ‘Notice that $M\ne\varnothing$’, which is simply false. And while the last sentence of that paragraph is correct, you really should justify it better. The whole paragraph could be reduced to this:

> If $M=\varnothing$, let $x\in X$; then $M\subseteq B_1(x)$, so (ii) is satisfied.

In your treatment of the case $M\ne\varnothing$ you define $\theta=\inf(M)$. This makes no sense: $X$ need not be any kind of ordered set, so the notion of infimum need not even apply to subsets of $X$. You can accomplish what you were trying to do simply by letting $x\in M$ be any point. Then $d(x,y)\le c$ for all $y\in M$, so $M\subseteq B_{c+1}(x)$.

Let me say something about the rest of the theorem. Notice that (iii) immediately implies (ii), so an efficient way to prove that (i), (ii), and (iii) are equivalent is to prove that (i) implies (iii) and that (ii) implies (i). Proving that (i) implies (iii) is almost as easy as proving that it implies (ii). There is no change in the argument if $M=\varnothing$. If $M\ne\varnothing$, let $x\in X$, and let $r=\inf\{d(x,y):y\in M\}$, the distance from $x$ to $M$.

- Show that $d(x,y)\le r+c$ for each $y\in M$, and conclude that $M\subseteq B_{r+c+1}(x)$.

After that it remains only to show that (ii) implies (i).

- Show that if $M\subseteq B_r(x)$, then $\operatorname{diam}(M)\le 2r$.

Answer (score 1):

The case $M=\emptyset$ is boring and irrelevant. Leave it out.

BTW, $\text{diam}(\emptyset) = -\infty$ or is undefined so your original definition of "bounded = finite diameter" also has an exception clause for the empty set.
So bounded= "empty" or finite diameter", presumably. If $M=\emptyset$ then (ii) and (iii) are both automatically true, for any $x \in X$, $r>0$, because $\emptyset \subseteq A$ is true for any $A$. So the equivalence holds and we move on to assume that $M \neq \emptyset$ throughout.

The circular steps then can become:

(i) $\implies $ (ii):
Let $R=\text{diam}(M)$, a finite real in $[0,+\infty)$. Pick any $x \in M$. Then (ii) holds for this $x$ and $r=R+1>0$: if $y \in M$ then $d(x,y) \le \text{diam}(M) = R < R+1$, so $M \subseteq B(x, r)$.

(ii) $ \implies $ (iii). Fix $x_0, r_0>0$ as in (ii). Let $x \in X$ be arbitrary. Define $r=d(x,x_0) + r_0 >0$. Then (iii) holds with this choice of $r$ for our $x$: let $m \in M$ then by (ii) we have $d(m,x_0) < r_0$ so  $$d(m, x) \le d(m, x_0) + d(x_0,x) < r_0 + d(x_0,x)=r$$ and so $M \subseteq B(x,r)$.

(iii) $\implies $ (i): let $m \in M$ and apply (iii) to get $r>0$ with $ M \subseteq B(m,r)$. It follows that for all $x,y \in M$ we have $d(x,y) \le d(x,m) + d(m,y) < 2r$ and so $\text{diam}(M) \le 2r < +\infty$ so $M$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\diam}{\operatorname{Diam}}$
$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$

**Attempt (following suggestions from you):**

Suppose $M$ is bounded. We want to see that $\exists_{x \in X}\left\{\exists_{r > 0}\left[ M \subseteq B_{r}(x)\right]\right\}$.

(iii) $\rightarrow$ (ii)

Suppose that $\forall_{x \in X}\left\{\exists_{r > 0}\left[ M \subseteq B_{r}(x)\right]\right\}$. We want to see that $\exists_{x \in X}\left\{\exists_{r > 0}\left[ M \subseteq B_{r}(x)\right]\right\}$.

By hypothesis it is true for any $x \in X$. Therefore, in particular, it is true for some $x \in X$. Hence, $\exists_{x \in X}\left\{\exists_{r > 0}\left[ M \subseteq B_{r}(x)\right]\right\}$.

(ii) $\rightarrow$ (i)

Suppose that $\exists_{x \in X}\left\{\exists_{r > 0}\left[ M \subseteq B_{r}(x)\right]\right\}$. We want to see that $M$ is bounded. Suppose by contradiction that $M$ is not bounded.

By hypothesis above, we have that $\diam(M) = \infty$. So there exists $m_{1},m_{2} \in M$ such that they are arbitrary far. It is a contradiction! Because the ball $B_{r}(x)$, which has a finite radius $r$, can not contain its points $m_{1}$ and $m_{2}$ but they are inside $M$.
(i) $\rightarrow$ (iii)

Suppose that $M$ is bounded. We want to see that $\forall_{x \in X}\left\{\exists_{r > 0}\left[ M \subseteq B_{r}(x)\right]\right\}$.

Notice that, by definition of bounded set, $\diam(X) = r$ for some $r \in \R$.

Let $x \in X$ and $x_{o \in M}$ and define $R = d(x,x_{o}) + r$. Then, consider the open ball $B_{R}(x)$. Let´s see that $M \subseteq B_{R}(x)$. To do it consider $s \in M$ we want to see that $s \in B_{R}(x)$. So, suppose by contradiction that $s \not\in B_{R}(x)$.
By definition of open ball:
$$d(s,x) \geq R$$
By definition of $R$:
$$d(s,x) \geq d(x,x_{0}) + r$$
Adding at both sides $-d(x,x_{0})$:
$$d(s,x) - d(x,x_{0}) \geq r$$
By the reverse triangle inequality we have that:
$$d(s,x_{0}) \geq r$$
It is a contradiction because we have that $r$ is the diameter of $M$ and the points $s$ and $x_{0}$, from there, can not have a bigger distance than $r$.

What do you think people?